# Update Your Amazon RDS SSL/TLS Certificates for a Rails 5 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-rds

I have received an email informing me that by March 5, 2020 I need to set a new SSL certificate for my RDS database.

What makes me confused in the email is the part about updating the client application:

> As previously communicated, the current CA expires on March 5, 2020,
>   requiring updates to all client applications and database instances
>   that connect using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)/Transport Layer Security
>   (TLS) with certificate verification. Client applications must add new
>   CA certificates to their trust stores, including root and intermediate
>   certificates where necessary. RDS database instances must separately
>   use new server certificates before this hard expiration date. If
>   you've missed previous communications on this subject, see the
>   Database Blog post for more information [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHWTF.png).

What does it mean? I have a standard Rails app where the config to the RDS is in the `database.yml` file:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: myapp_production
  username: username
  password: pass
  host: URLprod.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 5432
  pool: 30

staging:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: myapp_staging
  username: username
  password: pass
  host: URLstag.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 5432
  pool: 30
```

The one thing I have done for the staging RDS was that on this page
[image]
I clicked the **Update now** button. During that time, I've got this error message (although, the Rails app was still running):

```
Failsafe from rollbar-gem. PG::ConnectionBad: "could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "URLstag.rds.amazonaws.com" (IP) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

After approx 2 minutes, I looked to `Amazon RDS -> Databases -> my staging instance` and I see there this information:
[image]
which implies that the SSL certificate was updated for this RDS instance.

However, I did:

- not download any SSL certificate
- not upload anything on the EC2 instance (or anywhere else)
- not update any config files in the Rails app

Am I overlooking anything? Or is this the whole update of the certificate? It's still a bit unclear to me and I am trying to be sure before doing any changes on the production RDS database.

Comment: FWIW - I updated a few SSL Certificates, on multiple PSQL RDS instances, a few weeks ago to be in compliance as well. I too did not perform the unordered list points you made. After updating, I checked the ability to connect for admin users, via bastion host, then checked the connection from a lambda (both using existing connection information/keys) - all was well. I too thought the messaging was mildly confusing.

Comment: The messaging was subtle but important. If you didn’t rotate your certificates, applications that connect over SSL/TLS *and* do certificate verification (ie verify if the DB’s SSL certificate is still valid). If your application doest so certificate verification, you’re all set!